# phpMyAdmin, how to enable the db search field?

Tags: php, configuration, phpmyadmin

How can I enable the small searchfield above the list of my DBs in the navigation frame on the left?

```
$cfg['UseDbSearch']             = TRUE;
```

[UseDbSearch](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#UseDbSearch) does not enable it for me.

Answer (score 0):

did you find the config.inc

http://myeasylinux.wordpress.com/2010/07/31/phpmyadmin/

http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/config.inc.php

there you can enable it if you have privilege

Comment: Thanks for the note, I edited already the config.inc.php file! But I can not enable this specific feature.

Comment: I don't think so, it's just an setting for a PHP script, also other settings do work without restarting. I'm not sure if the config setting at all is the correct one.